# Select element from Jquery post return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, userscripts

I am trying to select an element from jquery post returning data. String is returning but when I try to select an element from returning html string, selection is always null. This is a userscript which is being loaded with greasemonkey.

```
refresh();

function refresh(___id,___action,___page){
            $.post("http://www.example.com", {auction_id:___id,action:___action,page:___page}, function(bidpage){
            var auction_id = $("#auction_id", bidpage).val();
            console.log(auction_id);
});
```

This post returns this data

```
    <html><head></head><body><input type="hidden" name="auction_id" id="auction_id" value="8583949"></body></html>
```

But `auction_id`  is always null. Cant find any solution to that. Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you get `bidpage` as string. You need to convert it to HTML first:

```
var auction_id = $("#auction_id", $( bidpage ) ).val();
```

As by jQuery API [`[context]`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) should be DOM Element, Document, or jQuery.

COMMENT:

Seems like jQuery strips `<html>` and `<body>` elements so you need to use:

```
var auction_id = $( bidpage ).val();
```

Comment: Seems like jQuery strips HTML and BODY elements so you need to use `var auction_id = $( bidpage ).val();`

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding your post data to a div:

```
<div id="appendpostdatahere"></div>


function refresh(___id,___action,___page){
  $.post("http://www.example.com", {auction_id:___id,action:___action,page:___page}, 
    function(bidpage){
      $('#appendpostdatahere').html(bidpage);
      var auction_id = $('#auction_id).val();
      console.log(auction_id);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not possible in my situation. And also I think the solution must be more efficient because I am working on seconds. It must be fast.